# Which net/ipv4 file contains the TCP window size parameter for the Linux Kernel?

Tags: unix, tcp, network-programming, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to tweak the TCP window size, so that I can improve the throughput between two network links. In order to do that, I want to understand completely how the UNIX kernel implements the TCP congestion control mechanism. I understand the theory of the mechanism perfectly, but I really want to see it implemented in the kernel code. Which file controls the TCP window size parameter?

Further, I would be very grateful for any good documentation on how the UNIX kernel implements the TCP congestion control mechanism. I don't want documentation on what the TCP control mechanism *is* (I have read a lot about it), but information on the kernel implementation would be great.

My motivation is to tweak the kernel to see if I can improve the performance. I know it's a hard thing to modify the kernel, but I have made a few changes to the RTO section of the kernel code, and was able to successfully compile. I just want help with the TCP window and its mechanism in the UNIX kernel.

Comment: Have you considered using `sysctl`? There are a zillion TCP tuning parameters in there that you can change at runtime without recompiling anything.

Comment: What you are telling is to keep the max. limit of the window size, but, I want to remove the exponential back-off, So, I am keeping the window size constant. I am not backing-off the window, even if the packet is lost on the network. Through, sysctl, I can change the general window, but, I can't tell TCP control mechanism in UNIX kernel to stop doing back-off. The only way, I found out is to remove the back-off code from the kernel. So, I want to know where is this file??

Comment: cd net/ipv4 ; grep backoff * . You are not going to be able to outsmart all the thousands and thousands of hours already put into TCP though. Tune the window sizes and socket buffers instead.

Comment: How do I tune the window sizes????. I mean in which file of the net/ipv4 file should I make the changes in order to play with them...

Answer (score 1):

net/ipv4/tcp_output.c, function `__tcp_select_window`

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.1/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L1842

and `tcp_select_window`

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.1/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L254

And net/ipv4/tcp_input.c `tcp_ack_update_window` is updater of local window after request from remote.

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.1/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L3447